# Gatsby and GraphQL: query pdf file using <StaticQuery/>

Tags: graphql, gatsby

I am very new to graphQL.

Inside `src` I have a `data` folder which contains a pdf named `my_cv.pdf`

Problem: I am unable to either load it in the browser or able to download it. I get an error `There's not a page yet at /data.file.publicURL`

`gatsby.config.js`

```
    {
      resolve: "gatsby-source-filesystem",
      options: {
        path: `${__dirname}/src/data/`,
        name: "data",
      },
    },
```

`my hero component`

this is inside the `render()` of the class component.

```
 <Resume href="data.file.publicURL" target="_blank">
    Download Resume
  </Resume>
```

this is how I am querying it.

```
<StaticQuery
    query={graphql`
      query {
        pdf: file(name: { eq: "my_cv.pdf" }) {
          name
          extension
          publicURL
        }
</StaticQuery>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are aliasing `file` as `pdf`, hence the nesting should be:

```
 <Resume href="data.pdf.publicURL" target="_blank">
    Download Resume
  </Resume>
```

If you use `StaticQuery` I think you may want to use something like:

```
import React from "react";
import { StaticQuery, graphql } from "gatsby";

export default function Header() {
  return (
    <StaticQuery
      query={graphql`
        query {
          pdf: file(name: { eq: "my_cv.pdf" }) {
            name
            extension
            publicURL
          }
        }
      `}
      render={(data) => (
        <Resume href="data.pdf.publicURL" target="_blank">
          Download Resume
        </Resume>
      )}
    />
  );
}
```

If you use `useStaticQuery` hook you can detach the logic from Resume of the `StaticQuery` component

```
import React from "react";
import { useStaticQuery, graphql } from "gatsby";

export default function Header() {
  const data = useStaticQuery(graphql`
    query {
      pdf: file(name: { eq: "my_cv.pdf" }) {
        name
        extension
        publicURL
      }
    }
  `);

  return (
    <Resume href="data.pdf.publicURL" target="_blank">
      Download Resume
    </Resume>
  );
}
```

In both cases, be sure that the GraphQL query is returning valid data.

Comment: It's a class component so, can't use the hook. I tried the first option. No luck !!

Comment: Can you `console.log(data)` before returning the `Resume` component? Just to know what's inside